# button in fragmentlist only responds once, then "releases" when clicking on the row

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

When I click the button in the ListView, I see the toast once. Then further clicks don't show anything when I click away from the button and in an empty space in the ListView, all the button click events that were not responding earlier appear at once (many toasts pop up one after another). Any idea how to fix this?

```
    class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter
    {

        HashMap<Integer, View> rowViews = new HashMap<Integer, View>();

        public Adapter(Context context) {
            super(context, R.layout.manage_member_row, members);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final View rowView;
            if(rowViews.containsKey(position)) {
                rowView = rowViews.get(position);
            } else {
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.manage_member_row, parent, false);
                ((TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.manage_member_row_name)).setText(members.get(position).name);
                rowViews.put(position, rowView);
            }

            ((Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.manage_member_row_delete)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "btnclick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.i("CRC", "called");
            return rowView;
        }




//manage_member_row.xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="8dip"
    android:paddingBottom="8dip"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/manage_member_row_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="name"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#53585E"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/manage_member_row_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="0dip"
        android:paddingBottom="0dip"
        android:paddingLeft="8dip"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#4E4E4E"
        android:background="#EAEAEA"
        android:paddingRight="8dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="REMOVE"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dip" />
</RelativeLayout>






//fragment_manage_members.xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="activities.ManageMembersActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
        android:dividerHeight="2.0dip"
        android:divider="#EEEDF3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/list" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "when I click away from the button and in an empty space in the ListView"?

Comment: i tab on the delete button, i get a toast, i tap on the delete button twice, get no toasts, i tab to the left of the delete button (no view there, just background) two toasts appear one after the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that sometimes position from getView are not synchronized have that problem before..

Also note that you use a `HashMap<Integer, View>` just to check if the view is already there that cost a lot of memory and will cause OutOfMemoryException..

so instead of putting it in a hashMap just create a ViewHolder for all your views. and add the object of the ViewHolder to the tag of the View..

**example:**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    if(view == null)
    {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_online_user_list_view_item, null);

        viewHolder.userName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.chat_online_user_name);

        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    //DO THE ON CLICK LISTENER HERE

    return view;
}

private class ViewHolder
{
    private TextView userName;
}
```